# null in atoi converts the value to 0

Tags: c++, c, atoi, strtol

In my program, I have a char array (char data[]) from which i have to extract the data and store it in an integer variable(value). To do so, I have used atoi in my program. Problem is that I sometime receive null in the char array(data). If i use atoi on this value, I get the value  0 in integer variable instead of (null)

The real function is quite big and I cannot post the entire code here. From function mentioned below, I hope you guys will get some idea about what I am doing here.

```
Get_Data(char data[])
{
    int value;
    value = atoi(p);
}
```

I recently read that we should use strtol instead of atoi. I tried that too. but I am still getting 0 in variable value.

I want to know which function should i use so that i get (null) in integer variable value?

By null, I mean empty character array here

Please provide solutions specific to the problem. In the above function, if data gets empty char value, how do i make sure that my int variable value also gets empty value and not zero??

Comment: You can't store `null` in a `int` variable in C/C++.

Comment: When you say "null" do you mean an empty char array or the string "null"?

Comment: @Holt It depends on what he means by "null".  You can definitely store a null character in an `int`, and on may systems, you can store a null pointer constant in an `int` as well.

Comment: @doctorlove : I meant empty char array..could you please suggest any solution for this

Comment: Try checking the length of the string first?

Comment: @doctorlove: I have to insert the values in database even if they are empty/no-values

Comment: @Kung-fu-panda `int` can only hold int values, not "character array" or "null". You could use `strtol`. The way to detect if `strtol` fails is to inspect what happens to the second argument.

Comment: @Kung-fu-panda: There's no such thing as an "empty" `int` value.

Answer (score 3):

atoi return zero for

> If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a
>   valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either
>   str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion
>   is performed and zero is returned.

Also you requrement for returning `NULL` is not possible because you assign those value in `int` and `int` can't hold not `NULL`.

Comment: Except that on most machines, an `int` can hold `NULL`; `NULL` is a "null pointer constant", not a null pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze you say in this sense `int  *ptr = NULL;` right?

Comment: Sort of.  What I'm really saying is that `int i = NULL;` is perfectly legal, and with most compilers, won't even elicit a warning.  (g++ is the only compiler I know of which warns.)

Comment: NULL is defined as 0 in most implementations.

Comment: @JamesKanze You're talking meaningless corner theories.  Once you store `NULL` in an `int`, it becomes just another number and ceases to be `NULL`.  In most sane implementations we even know that number is `0`.  If you know you have `NULL` data and that's at all important to you, use an `if` statement for goodness sakes.  (Oh, and it's **undefined** to pass `NULL` to `atoi()` even though it'll likely return `0` 99.9% of the time it could also SEGFAULT, so yeah...)

Comment: Did anyone here has experienced that sometime the function `atoi` generates SIGSEGV and sometimes the value 0 ?

Comment: @darth_coder yes, I just had it seg faulting on my raspberry pi, but not on Ubuntu x86_64. (I did not check the actual return value on the latter, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Because [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/) tries to read as much as it can.

You should use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) instead , like this:

```
char* endptr = NULL
char* myString = "OUPS";
long n = strtol(myString, &endptr, 10);

if (*endptr != '\0') {
  // ERROR
}
```

Read the reference link for more explanation (and example too).

Comment: Another way would be to check endptr == myString since it gets set to whenever no conversion took place (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that good?

There is no Integer value in C++ spelled as `null`

NULL in an integer form is 0 only.